# Centos 7 Drivers issues on HP sleekbook 15-b001ee

Tags: centos, wifi

I am fresh to linux and centos. I have installed centos with GNOME desktop successfully but after signing to my account couldn't find Sound and Wifi working. I have google a lot but everything is install through yum and I can't install anything because I don't have internet access.

Can someone please help me installing wifi device drivers or am I missing something with centos installation.

I have Ralink Wifi adapter installed with my HP sleekbook.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found a package here: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/29069833/dir/centos_7/com/NetworkManager-wifi-1.0.0-14.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

You can install the NetworkManager-wifi package to view the graphic interface for connecting wifi devices.

I found the solution at http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/18/connect-to-wifi-network-from-command-line-in-linux/

I installed `iw` and `wpa_supplicant` and followed the steps and now connected my wifi successfully.